# reverse order in a csv

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a CSV file such as:

```
input.csv
1,2,3,10
4,5,6
7,8,9,12,28,30
```

I want to reverse the columns in this file which means:

```
output.csv
10,3,2,1
6,5,4
30,28,12,9,8,7
```

I know how to do it for a fixed column count, but if the column count varies, what should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `perl`, assuming the fields in your CSV don't have embedded commas, newlines, etc.:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join ",", reverse split /,/' input.csv
```

Comment: The safe way would use `Text::CSV`, for if the assumption fails.

Answer (score 9):

CSV can't always be processed by simply splitting by lines and then commas, since fields may sometimes have commas or newlines themselves. To be able to include those characters, fields must be quoted.

This is a simple solution you can call from the shell that uses a proper csv parser:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'CSV.filter(&:reverse!)' input.csv
```

If you don't have ruby, this works with both python 2 and 3.

```
python -c $'import csv; import sys\nfor r in csv.reader(sys.stdin): r.reverse(); csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerow(r)' < input.csv > output.csv
```

Here it is in multiple lines:

```
python < input.csv > output.csv -c '
import csv
import sys

for r in csv.reader(sys.stdin):
  r.reverse()
  csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerow(r)
'
```

Here are some examples where this will work where solutions with simple comma splitting won't work:

input.csv

```
1,"2,3"
```

output.csv

```
"2,3",1
```

input.csv

```
1,"
2"
```

output.csv

```
"
2",1
```

Comment: i ran ruby and i liked it.  mac os 11.2.2 ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]).

Answer (score 8):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk  'BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","                       # set the field delimiter
}
{                                  # execute only on non empty line
  for(i=NF;i>=1;i--)               # loop through all elements
    printf "%s", $i (i==1?ORS:OFS) # print the parameter together with the comma or newline 
}' input.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

Using **GNU** `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -t',' reverse --no-strict <infile
10,3,2,1
6,5,4
30,28,12,9,8,7
```

from [`man datamash`](http://manpages.org/datamash):

```
-t, --field-separator=X
    use X instead of TAB as field delimiter

reverse
    reverse field order in each line

--no-strict
    allow lines with varying number of fields
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -l -a -F, -n -e 'print join ("," , reverse  @F)'  input.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '{for(i=NF;i>=1;i--)printf("%s,",$i);printf "\n"}' input.txt | sed "s/$,//"
```